# How to use AVLoadingIndicatorView programmatically without defining in xml file?

Tags: android

I want to use AVLoadingIndicatorView in my AsyncTask but without  defining it  in xml file.Is it possible or not ?

Comment: `ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);`

Comment: I want to use  AVLoadingIndicatorView . check this link : : https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView.

Comment: @SharanjeetKaur Check my answer, that might help you,

Answer (score 6):

Basically *AVLoadingIndicatorView* is extended from View. So it need a UI container to get visible. setVisibility won't work because no parent view container is associated with it.

Try to create custom *ProgressDialog* and assign *AVLoadingIndicatorView* to it.

```
AVLoadingIndicatorView avLoadingIndicatorView=new AVLoadingIndicatorView(MainActivity.this);     
avLoadingIndicatorView.setIndicator("BallSpinFadeLoader"); 
avLoadingIndicatorView.setIndicatorColor(R.color.colorPrimar‌​y);

// Create progress dialog
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(activity_context);
pd.setIndeterminate(true);
pd.show();
// Set custom view(Loading Indicator View) after showing dialog
pd.setContentView(avLoadingIndicatorView);
```

Comment: Now, ProgressDialog is Deprecated. Can you share latest update for same flow ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use as following. For other use, You'd better look at the source code [AVLoadingIndicatorView](https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/wang/avi/AVLoadingIndicatorView.java).

```
AVLoadingIndicatorView indicator = new AVLoadingIndicatorView(context);
```

Comment: This is my code  :                                                     AVLoadingIndicatorView avLoadingIndicatorView=new AVLoadingIndicatorView(MainActivity.this);
        avLoadingIndicatorView.setIndicator("BallSpinFadeLoader");
        avLoadingIndicatorView.setIndicatorColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
        avLoadingIndicatorView.show();
        avLoadingIndicatorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                  It is showing blank screen

Comment: You must add avLoadingIndicatorView to view tree.